For Django, 'sql_server.pyodbc' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported
I'm new to Django and trying to set up a DB Connection with SQL Server db.
Earlier we had MySQL which was working fine, I'm having trouble connecting to SQL Server
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'AAAAA',
        'USER': 'AAAAA',
        'PASSWORD': 'AAAAA',
        'HOST': 'AAAAA',
        'PORT': '1433',
    }
}

Error: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'sql_server.pyodbc' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
Tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver16
doesn't work.
Also, I have 2 question
Is it a good idea to use third party library/drivers for SQL Server? will it affect the performance compared to MySQL?

Maybe you can try some of the solutions of this related question

If you're using the mssql-django backend from Microsoft then the ENGINE property should simply be mssql.
